# Insert values at the same row index from two different loops in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I started to work with pandas very recently, and my issue is the following: I have two loops, that generates each 10 values. What I want to do is to insert at the bottom of my data frame the generated values, in such a way that the index is the same for both loops.

Here is a mock-up example, that is quite close of what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

randint = {'rand': [10,52,99,8],'rand2': [541,632,789,251], 'rand3': [1,3,4,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(randint, columns = ['rand','rand2', "rand3"])

i = j = len(df)
for x in range(10):
    rand = random.randint(1,101)
    rand2 = random.randint(1,1001)
    df.loc[df.index[i], "rand"] = rand
    df.loc[df.index[i], "rand2"] = rand2
    i = i + 1

for y in range(10):
    rand3 = random.randint(1,11)
    df.loc[df.index[j], "rand3"] = rand3
    j = j + 1

print(df)
```

So, what I would like is to have for instance at row 5 the first set of rand, rand2, rand3 at the same row, and so forth (e.g.: for x and y = 1, I would have the three values at the same row, for x and y = 2, same thing, etc...). The issue is that I have read that it was not a good idea to iterate with pandas (and obviously, pandas is raising me the error "*index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4*"), but I really have trouble to understand the pandas syntax and I'm a bit lost on how I am supposed to tackle this issue. Thank you for your help.

Expected output:

At first, my dataframe would look like this:

| rand | rand2 | rand3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 541 | 1 |
| 52 | 632 | 3 |
| 99 | 789 | 4 |
| 8 | 251 | 1 |

Now, let us imagine that the first time in the first  loop (so for x = 1) , rand = 8, rand2 = 455, and for the first time of the second loop (so for y=1), rand3 = 7.

So now, I would like to add the values obtained to the last row, in such a way that my dataframe would look like this:

| rand | rand2 | rand3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 541 | 1 |
| 52 | 632 | 3 |
| 99 | 789 | 4 |
| 8 | 251 | 1 |
| 8 | 455 | 7 |

The issue is that I don't really know to indicate to pandas that I want to have the same index for the two loops. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: Can you post some expected output? Is it that you expect `row5` to be equal to be `10` + `541` + `1`? [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: For instance, if rand = 8, rand2= 455 and rand3= 7, I would like to have at row 5: 8, 455, 7. And so forth for the next set of values of rand, rand2 and rand3.

Comment: **Use `df.concat()`.** You never need to do this iterative indexing with `for x in range(len(df))` and `.loc[...]`.

Comment: This answers your question, see the `concat` section. [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the case, but in your example the second loop is working on `rand2` column and not `rand3`. Also, when you use `df.loc` use the value of `i` or `j` (not df.index[i/j])

```
i = j = len(df)
for x in range(10):
    rand = random.randint(1,101)
    rand2 = random.randint(1,1001)
    df.loc[i, "rand"] = rand
    df.loc[i, "rand2"] = rand2
    i = i + 1
for y in range(10):
    rand3 = random.randint(1,11)
    df.loc[j, "rand3"] = rand3
    j = j + 1
print(df)  

    rand  rand2  rand3
0   10.0  541.0    1.0
1   52.0  632.0    3.0
2   99.0  789.0    4.0
3    8.0  251.0    1.0
4   37.0  902.0    6.0
5   65.0  717.0   11.0
6   95.0  345.0    6.0
7   81.0  218.0    9.0
8   90.0  233.0   10.0
9   15.0  918.0    6.0
10  62.0  775.0   10.0
11  27.0  955.0    4.0
12  43.0   17.0    2.0
13  69.0   41.0    8.0
```

Pandas way of doing this is like that:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.DataFrame({
    'rand': np.random.randint(1,101,10), 
    'rand2': np.random.randint(1,1001,10), 
    'rand3': np.random.randint(1,11,10)})

   rand  rand2  rand3
0    50    877      5
1     9    929      5
2    23    605      7
3    52    205      4
4    39    341      6
5    17    455      7
6    11    505      7
7    68    647     10
8    66    920      6
9    63    386      9
```

Comment: Oh shoot, the rand2 was a typo! I'm not at my place but I'll try your code as soon as I can.

Comment: The OP clearly just needs `df.concat()`. This should be a one-liner.

Comment: 100%. I agree this is not the case, but the problem in his question was the actual code. Whether or not it's a good/bad code - there is no doubt about it.